# Adding an arraylist of durations using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stopwatch class that measures the time it takes to produce reports:

```
public class Stopwatch {
  public String report;
  public Instant startTime;
  public Instant endTime;
  public Duration duration;
}
```

While reports are run the timings and duration are gathered:

```
private ArrayList<Stopwatch> _reportStats;
```

In the end I'd like to know the total duration for all the reports such as:

```
Duration total = Duration.ZERO; // was null;
for (Stopwatch s: _reportStats) {
  total = total.plus(s.duration);
}
```

Except I'd like to use a stream and a reduce but I can't get the syntax correct:

```
Duration total = _reportStats.stream().reduce(... syntax ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` with an ***identity value (`Duration.ZERO`) for sum***, and define `Duration.plus` as the accumulator :

```
Duration total = _reportStats.stream()
        .map(Stopwatch::getDuration)
        .reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus);
```

Comment: Thanks the main problem was I was missing the `map (object -> object.field)` as you have there `Stopwatch::getDuration`